Extract failed user and respective data using Bean shell Scripting - JMeter
I would like to write a BeanShell script to extract the failed data i.e. Login, Search from JMeter script to a file so that I can directly pass the failed data to the concerned team for data correction.
I tried using Sample Data Writer for error extraction but it is a tedious process when data is huge as I have to manually go through each error request and put it into a file.
I'm currently using Apache JMeter 5.5 version.
